# Number density of holes in an intrinsic semiconductor having light and heavy hole band

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Say the dispersion is isotropic:

$$E=E_0+\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}$$

Then the density of states in the valence bands are given by

$$g_{lh}(E)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi^2\hbar^3}m_{lh}^{3/2}\sqrt{E_v-E}$$
$$g_{hh}(E)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi^2\hbar^3}m_{hh}^{3/2}\sqrt{E_v-E}$$

If I want to calculate the total number density of holes without omitting the light holes for their smaller number, **which integral is the correct one**?

$$p = \int_{-\infty}^{E_v}[1-f(E)][g_{lh}(E)+g_{hh}(E)]dE$$

or

$$p=\int_{-\infty}^{E_v}\left[1-\frac{1}{2}f(E)\right][g_{lh}(E)+g_{hh}(E)]dE$$
................................

I was considering the second form since the possibility of an electron occupying *one of the bands at energy between $E$ and $E+dE$* is half of the probability of it occupying *the energy between $E$ and $E+dE$*. Think of finding the number density for both bands separately, then add them together:

$$p=p_{lh}+p_{hh} = \int_{-\infty}^{E_v}\left[1-\frac{1}{2}f(E)\right]g_{lh}(E)dE+\int_{-\infty}^{E_v}\left[1-\frac{1}{2}f(E)\right]g_{hh}(E)dE$$

Meanwhile, for the first integral I thought that the possibility of an electron being absent from the energy range is $1-f(E)$ and the density of states available in the energy range is simply $g_{lh}+g_{hh}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first integral is correct. $f(E)$ is the probability of occupation of any state with energy $E$. If for instance there are two degenerate states (let's call them $A$ and $B$) with energy $E$, $f(E)$ is the probability that state $A$ will be occupied. It is also the probability that $B$ will be occupied. This is sometimes called marginal probabililty. $f(E)$ is not the probability of both $A$ and $B$ being occupied, and it is not the probability of either $A$ or $B$ being occupied.

In semiconductors like Si, Ge and GaAs, the hole *density of states effective mass* is defined as
$$m_h^*=\left({m_{hh}^*}^{3/2}+{m_{lh}^*}^{3/2}\right)^{2/3}.$$
Note that the heavy and light hole contributions are additive. This facilitates the calculation of hole density as simply
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{E_v}\left[1-f(E)\right]\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi^2\hbar^3}{m_{h}^*}^{3/2}\sqrt{E_v-E}\ dE = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{E_v}\left[1-f(E)\right]g_h(E)\ dE.$$

Note also that if $m^*_{lh}$ (and hence $g_{lh}(E)$) is indeed small enough to be negligible, your second integral would underestimate the hole density by about half.